# How can I check if a custom CA certificate is installed on CentOS?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

We are having a custom CA certificate for our infrastructure

I wrote puppet module to install a CA certificate:

```
exec {"update-ca-trust extract":
    path => ['/bin', '/usr/bin', '/sbin'],
    provider => shell,
    command => "update-ca-trust extract",
    unless => "awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '/BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt | grep Custom",
}
```

My question about only this string:

```
awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '/BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt | grep CustomCAcertificate
```

Is there a better way to check for the presence of a custom CA certificate on CentOS?

Comment: Check it for what?  What do you need to know/prove?

Comment: check exists custom CA certificate on CentOS

Comment: @Zoredache He is checking whether a CA certificate is present on the system.

Comment: _Another_ way -- I don't claim better -- if you have the cert alone in a PEM file, do `openssl verify $certfile` (letting it default the truststore) and see whether it finds the cert or says 'error 18 at 0 depth lookup'

Comment: Dont work 
#####################
awk -v cmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '/BEGIN/{close(cmd)};{print | cmd}' < /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt | grep MyCertCA
unable to load certificate
139839020550048:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE 
###################
echo $?
1


################
openssl verify MyCertCA-RootCA.crt
MyCertCA-RootCA.crt: DC = xx, DC = MyDC, CN = MyCertCA-RootCA
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
#############
echo $?
0